# I'm trying to do FB.login to get the get only email, name and location - but Facebook API always requests user for "friend lists" access permission

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a simple app that allows user to populate fields from his facebook account. All I want is user email, name and location - why in the world even the simplest login without any additional permission request results in facebook API asking user to allow access to friends list...?? I don't need friends list.. - is there a way to disable asking for friend list permissions?

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
```

Message user would get is something like this:

Example.com would like to access your public profile, **friend list** and email address.

I don't wanna request "friend list" - is there a way to disable that?

Comment: You need to specify 'scope' in FB.login. Check out their [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) page under 'permission' section.

Comment: Also check if there is any scope defined in the App Settings that might be getting added incorrectly.

Comment: I specify scope: 'email' - doesn't change anything - still requires friends list.

Comment: Accessing a user’s friend list is included in the very basic permissions a user gives you by simply connecting to your app. Has been this way before – but FB recently rephrased their description for those basic permissions, so that users are more aware what they will share with an app by just logging in to it. And there is no way _not_ to request friend list access, because as I said it is a _basic_ permission. (Don’t know if the method in Dex’ answer works – but I would be careful, this would be “circumventing” FB’s intentions, and they might punish that at some point.)

Answer (score 1):

Public user profile information and the friends list seems to included in the default permission set, i.e. even when you specify an empty "`scope`".

From [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/):

> When a user logs into your app and you request no additional
>   permissions, the app will have access to only the user's **public profile**
>   and also their **friend list**. Public profile refers to the
>   following properties by default:
>
> - id
> - name
> - first_name
> - last_name
> - link
> - username
> - gender
> - locale
> - age_range